# adjusting row height in phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

I've just been trying unsuccessfully to get phpexcel (PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007) to automatically adjust row height based on content, when that content contains newline characters. At the moment, only the final line is visible. I've tried setting the row height to -1 for the row in question and the whole column i.e.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(65)->setRowHeight(-1);
```

and

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);
```

but it makes no difference. Help appreciated. Cheers

Comment: You also have to tell PHPExcel/MS Excel that the cell should be wrapped (alignment)

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A65')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);`